# I keep getting "Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed."

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gitlab-ci

I am deploying an a docker image to AWS elastic beanstalk using gitlab pipeline. My image is present in my gitlab registry, whenever I run the pipeline it runs successfully but I keep getting this errors in my beanstalk.

```
Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed.

Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.

[Instance: i-0331810401b751bff] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..

Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].

Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0331810401b751bff'. Aborting the operation.

Failed to deploy application.

During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

This is my job for the deployment to beanstalk

```
  variables:
    APP_NAME: my website
    ENV_NAME: "Mywebsite-env"
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli:2.11.14
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: deploy
  environment: production
  script:
    - aws s3 cp Dockerrun2.aws.json s3://$AWS_BUCKET/Dockerrun2.aws.json
    - aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name "$APP_NAME" --version-label $APP_VERSION --source-bundle S3Bucket=$AWS_BUCKET,S3Key=Dockerrun2.aws.json
    - aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name $ENV_NAME --version-label $APP_VERSION --application-name "$APP_NAME"
```

This is the content of my Dockerrun2.aws.json file

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest",
      "Authentication": {
        "Type": "registry",
        "Registry": {
          "URL": "$CI_REGISTRY",
          "Username": "$CI_DEPLOY_USER",
          "Password": "$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD"
        }
      }
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
```

Where `$CI_DEPLOY_USER`, `$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD` variables were created in the GitLab CICD tab.

`$CI_DEPLOY_USER` value is the name I chose when creating a `Deploy tokens` and `$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD` value is the generated token. These are stored as my variables in CICD.

Please how can I deploy to AWS Beanstalk without these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I used this configuration instead for my Dockerrun.aws.json file

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
  },
  "Authentication": {
    "Bucket": "$AWS_BUCKET",
    "Key": "config.json"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

For my config.json file I used this configuration

```
{
    "auths": {
        "$CI_REGISTRY": {
            "auth": "$GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN"
        }
    }
}
```

To get the `"$GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN"` value you have to create a Deploy token in GitLab, use the created token and user name to login into your registry from your local machine using this command:

`docker login $YOUR_GITLAB_REGISTRY -u $CREATED_USER -p $CREATED_TOKEN`

Once you've logged in, run this command to get the token to be used by AWS EBS.

`cat ~/.docker/config.json` 
Save the token as your `"$GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN"` token.